# Batch video convert with FFmpeg: combine image and audio

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion

I have a folder full of audio file with .mp3 .amr and .wav extension. I have a image.jpg. What I want is combine the image.jpg with every audio file in that folder and convert them to separate vidoe.mp4 file. How do I do it with FFmpge?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two other answered questions that should help you achieve your goal.

"Combine one image + one audio file to make one video using FFmpeg"
source: [Combine one image + one audio file to make one video using FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg)

The order of options in the command line matters. The following works for my case:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -y -i image8.jpg -i sound11.amr -acodec copy -vcodec mjpeg result.avi
```

---

In a more general case, where `image.jpg` and `audio.wav` are your input, you can use the following command, adapted from [the FFmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

This would use the `libx264` encoder and provide you with better compression than the MJPEG codec used above. The audio is AAC, with the built-in `ffmpeg` AAC encoder.

---

"How to do a for loop in windows command line?"
source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192039/how-to-do-a-for-loop-in-windows-command-line

The commandline interpreter does indeed have a FOR construct that you can use from the command prompt or from within a batch file.

For your purpose, you probably want something like:

```
FOR %i IN (*.ext) DO my-function %i
```

Which will result in the name of each file with extension *.ext in the current directory being passed to my-function (which could, for example, be another .bat file).

The (*.ext) part is the "filespec", and is pretty flexible with how you specify sets of files. For example, you could do:

```
FOR %i IN (C:\Some\Other\Dir\*.ext) DO my-function %i
```

To perform an operation in a different directory.

There are scores of options for the filespec and FOR in general. See

```
HELP FOR
```

from the command prompt for more information.

Okay the content is now contained in the post itself thanks to a message from Donald Duck :D

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...