# How to join a picture and audio file on ffmpeg multiple times?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, merge, combine

what I am trying to do is merge audio and picture files on ffmpeg multiple times. For example, this line of code (taken from [Combine one image + one audio file to make one video using FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg)) allows me to merge one audio and picture file in order to create one mp4

I am wondering if it is possible to add a second set of audio and pictures and have them play right after the first set of the audio and picture (Video plays with picture 1 displayed and audio 1 played then it goes over to picture 2 and audio 2)

Code for reference:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

Thank you to everyone who helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -i 01.jpg -i 01.wav -i 02.jpg -i 02.wav -i 03.jpg -i 03.wav -filter_complex "[0][1][2][3][4][5]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

This assumes that all inputs have the same width, height, audio sample rate, number of audio channels, etc. If not you can add more filterchains before using concat.