# ffmpeg command fails on large jpeg images

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Using this example command:

**ffmpeg -i  -c:v libx265 -crf 0 output.mp4**

from this thread:

**[ffmpeg settings for converting still images to video for archival](https://superuser.com/questions/1212023/ffmpeg-settings-for-converting-still-images-to-video-for-archival?newreg=a47d41d376174f4687044af410aab3b0)**

I can convert a series of 1024 by 576 images in one directory

However

the full resolution images, at 5152 by 2896 fail, with this strange return error:

**Killed    6 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x**

I suspect I may be running out of RAM on my little Raspberry Pi and, if so I'd appreciate any suggestions how to work around this by creating a swap file or something.

Comment: Add `-g 5` and check. Increase the number till it it doesn't crash. Basically, ffmpeg is referencing all encoded images from the last keyframe it generated and that may be exhausting the resources. `g` sets the interval between keyframes.

Comment: @Mulvya thanks for the suggestion but I believe the option -crf 0 is lossless which I suspect means no resulting keyframes.

Comment: That's not true. There's always keyframes, except when the stream is intra-coded. In which case, every frame is a "key" frame.

Comment: @Mulvya, You are correct but surely 'lossless' is intra-coded, ie. no Spatial or Temporal compression whatsoever.  Otherwise it would be 'lossy'.

Comment: No. Referring to other regions (spatial) or frames (temporal) does not preclude lossless compression. It's lossy if the prediction is imperfect but it doesn't have to be.