# Huge file size difference between lossless HEVC and FFV1

Tags: video, ffmpeg, lossless, h.265

I made a music video with a still image (input.jpg ≈ 1 MB) and a music (input.wav ≈ 20 MB) using FFmpeg. Why do I get such a huge difference in file size between the video generated with the lossless HEVC codec (output.mkv ≈ 70 MB) and that generated with the FFV1 codec (output.mkv ≈ 10 GB)?

The issued commands

- for lossless HEVC:

```bsh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.jpg -i input.wav \
       -c:v hevc -crf 0 -c:a flac -s 3840x2160 -r 60 -shortest output.mkv
```

- for FFV1:

```bsh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.jpg -i input.wav \
       -c:v ffv1 -c:a flac -s 3840x2160 -r 60 -shortest output.mkv
```

It looks like either the provided parameters for lossless HEVC are incorrect (in the sense not really lossless) or FFV1 is a terrible codec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FFV1 is intra-coded so each frame is compressed independently of other frames; HEVC is typically inter-coded.

Assuming you're using libx265, you have to add `-x265-params lossless=1` for true lossless mode (`-crf 0` isn't). At the end of encoding, x265 should print a line displaying `lossless compression ratio`.

x265 has better intra-prediction than x264 and I expect, FFV1, so lossless compression is more efficient. But it takes more resources to decode.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105093/discussion-on-answer-by-gyan-huge-file-size-difference-between-lossless-hevc-and).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your patience. I am going to accept your answer. Just before I do, in the interest of the reader, could you add to your answer the two important points that we have been discussing in these comments? a) HEVC can also use intra-frame prediction only like FFV1 with `-g 1` since FFmpeg 4.3, and with `-x265-params keyint=1` before FFmpeg 4.3; b) `-crf 0` has no effect with `-x265-params lossless=1` so should not be used. That will make your answer even more awesome.

Comment: I think `b` is already covered, and `a` is not directly relevant to the Q as asked.

Comment: About a), for me it is very relevant to know that I can get the same behaviour as FFV1. About b), your answer does not explicitly state that `-crf 0` has no effect when combined with `-x265-params lossless=1`. So I have been wondering if I should keep it or not (for you it might be obvious since you are an FFmpeg maintainer, but me I am a new FFmpeg user, like most future readers of this post). In addition, with the H.264 codec, `-crf 0` _does_ mean true lossless mode (cf. [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1212038/563129)), which is very confusing, so a little explanation would not harm.